# SAPUI5: how to getBindProperty from property that was binded from model?

Tags: javascript, sapui5

I have this code:

```
//create table
tableContent=getcontent();

    var oTable2 = new sap.ui.table.Table(tableId, {
        width : "100%",
        visibleRowCount: tableContent.length,
        selectionMode : sap.ui.table.SelectionMode.None,
        resizable : false,
        flexible : false
    });

    var img = new sap.m.Image({
            press: function() {console.log(img.getProperty("src"))
        }});

    img.bindProperty("src", "src");

    oTable2.addColumn(new sap.ui.table.Column({
            label: new sap.ui.commons.Label({ text: "" }),
            template: img,
            autoResizable: false,
            width : '10%'
        }));
    var oModel2 = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel();
    oModel2.setData({ modelData: tableContent });
    oTable2.setModel(oModel2);
    oTable2.bindRows("/modelData");
    oTable2.sort(oTable2.getColumns()[0]);
    oTable2.placeAt(containingDivId);
```

Problem is that I am defining a property in the constructor that should print the `img` source:

```
var img = new sap.m.Image({
            press: function() {console.log(img.getProperty("src"))
        }});
```

But when I am trying to take it like this:

```
img.bindProperty("src", "src");
```

I am getting blank text (nothing).

How can I get this bounded value? Any other function?

Second question: How can I add custom property to `img?` Say I wont to have in img: src, alt and myCustomTxt. How can I add the property `myCustomTxt`?

***update:***

I've tried:

```
  var img = new sap.m.Image({
        "src" : "assets/images/btn-X.png",
        "press" : function(event) {
            var binding = event.getSource().getBindingInfo("src").binding;

                console.log(binding.getValue());

        }
    });
```

but I am getting this error when pressing a image:

```
cart-module.js:151 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'binding' of undefined(…)
```

Thanks!

Comment: Can you post your JSON model?

Comment: yes but one question before:  can you tell me how can I bind an event? say I want to bind the press event in a image sapui5 element.. I can't do it with bindProperty() because it is event. not property.. any way to do this bind with event?

Comment: Forgive me but that is a very fundamental question. If you have not seen them, could you go and work your way through the tutorials at https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/guide/8b49fc198bf04b2d9800fc37fecbb218.html - you will find them very useful and they will answer questions about models, bindings, events, and views including questions you have not come to yet.

Comment: In this you don't have a binding as you're setting the value directly!

Answer (score 3):

I assume you have a property called "src" in the each record of your model. Then you can bind it as follows:

```
new sap.m.Image({
    "path" : "{src}",
    "press" : function(event) {
        var binding = event.getSource().getBindingInfo("src").binding;
        if (binding) {
            jQuery.sap.log.debug(binding.getValue());
        }
     }
});
```

To add custom attributes you can use method **addCustomData** which expects and instance of **sap.ui.core.CustomData**.

```
img.addCustomData(new sap.ui.core.CustomData({ "key" : myCustomTxt, "value" : "myCustomText" });
```

Comment: I just want to go to url1 when I press the first img, go to url2 when pressing the 2nd img..

Comment: I have index paramter for each record.. I just want something like new sap.m.Image.bindProperty("press", "callFunc(index)"),

Comment: Please add this information ([first img, second img] to the question. Solutions provided in comments are not favoured.